# The ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES function

Tags: arima

I am very new to programming and have what I believe is a basic question I can't find the answer to.

I am trying to use this function, the statement is below :

SELECT
*
FROM
ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES(MODEL `mydataset.my_arima_plus_model`,
STRUCT(0.9 AS anomaly_prob_threshold),
TABLE `mydataset.my_time_series_data_table`)
#it is from this link
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-detect-anomalies

My question is, how can I create the table for "TABLE `mydataset.my_time_series_data_table`)" and what should I put in the columns for headers and data?

Answer (score 0):

The `mydataset.my_time_series_data_table` is the data that you want to detect the anomalies. In the [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-detect-anomalies#arima_plus_model_example_with_input_data_as_a_query_statement) that you linked, the timestamp is `date` and time series data is `temperature`, as mentioned on that page:

> .. and `TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL`, and the `TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL`
> column names are `date` and `temperature` ...

So,

> what should I put in the columns for headers and data?

Your table should have at least `date` and `temperature` two columns.